# Can we create "asymmetric" EPR pairs in experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

Asymmetric here is just for lack of a better word.

What I am looking for are experiments that can create a simple EPR pair but without 50% 50% chance of each state.

As I understand from standard books of quantum mechanics there is no particular reason to have something like the following state:
$$\left| \psi \right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 00 \right>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| 11 \right>$$

and in principal you could have the following:
$$\left| \psi \right>=\frac{1}{2}\left| 00 \right>+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| 11 \right>$$

Since they both are members of the same 4D Hilbert space.

However I have never seen an example of this happening in an experiment. Always the state will be 1/2,1/2.

Is there a reference for something like this? 
What key-word I could use to find it?

Comment: Of course you can have those kinds of states... experiments often aim for the Bell pair because it’s the “most entangled”.